Did Stilgar have previous "visitors" who he thought could be a potential Mahdi or Lisan al-Gaib?
Spoilers all around.
This part is not in the book, solely in the movie. And since the movie is not considered canon, I guess this question could be handled in the movie's own universe.
In the movie Dune: Part Two, we see that after Stilgar brings Paul and Jessica to Sietch Tabr, he presents himself before a sort of council to make his defensive arguments for bringing foreigners to the sietch. At this point, he claims that "he saw signs", upon which he's subjected to jovial mockery, encountering the question "again?!".
So, what would prompt this response from the council?

My impression was that Stilgar was a true believer who was looking for signs and so whatever he saw he tended to interpret as the prophecy coming true.
